# How to resize an image when resizing the window in JavaFX

Tags: java, eclipse, autoresize

I want an image to be resized automatically when the user drags the main window. Is that possible?

I have the following code that sets a window of a certain size. It also loads the image from an external URL.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    MenuBar menuBar=new MenuBar();
    Menu menuGame = new Menu("Game");
    MenuItem newGame = new MenuItem("New Game                F1");
    MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit                            F2");
    exit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            primaryStage.close();
        }

    });
    menuGame.getItems().addAll(newGame,new SeparatorMenuItem(),exit);
    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuGame);

    Image image = new Image("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/"
    + "javafx/images/javafx-documentation.png");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(image);


    VBox vbox=new VBox();
    StackPane root=new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().addAll(imageView);

    vbox.getChildren().addAll(menuBar,root);

    Scene scene= new Scene(vbox,400,400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.setMaxHeight(800);
    primaryStage.setMinHeight(400);
    primaryStage.setMaxWidth(1000);
    primaryStage.setMinWidth(800);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Minesweeper");
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFx image resizing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951284/javafx-image-resizing)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing images to fit the parent node](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12635224/7255)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Applying the solution to [JavaFx image resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951284/javafx-image-resizing) to your sample code and resizing the window results in different image sizes for me.

[image: sizedefault]
[image: sizeresize]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.beans.value.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ImageResizer extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        MenuBar menuBar=new MenuBar();
        Menu menuGame = new Menu("Game");
        MenuItem newGame = new MenuItem("New Game                F1");
        MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit                            F2");
        exit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                primaryStage.close();
            }
        });
        menuGame.getItems().addAll(newGame,new SeparatorMenuItem(),exit);
        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(menuGame);

        Image image = new Image("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/"
                + "javafx/images/javafx-documentation.png");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(image);

        ImageViewPane viewPane = new ImageViewPane(imageView);

        VBox vbox=new VBox();
        StackPane root=new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().addAll(viewPane);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(menuBar,root);
        VBox.setVgrow(root, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene= new Scene(vbox,200,200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.setMaxHeight(400);
        primaryStage.setMinHeight(200);
        primaryStage.setMaxWidth(500);
        primaryStage.setMinWidth(400);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Minesweeper");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(); }
}





/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 * DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS FILE HEADER.
 */


/**
 *
 * @author akouznet
 */
class ImageViewPane extends Region {

    private ObjectProperty<ImageView> imageViewProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<ImageView>();

    public ObjectProperty<ImageView> imageViewProperty() {
        return imageViewProperty;
    }

    public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageViewProperty.get();
    }

    public void setImageView(ImageView imageView) {
        this.imageViewProperty.set(imageView);
    }

    public ImageViewPane() {
        this(new ImageView());
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewProperty.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setFitWidth(getWidth());
            imageView.setFitHeight(getHeight());
            layoutInArea(imageView, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
        }
        super.layoutChildren();
    }

    public ImageViewPane(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<ImageView>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ImageView> arg0, ImageView oldIV, ImageView newIV) {
                if (oldIV != null) {
                    getChildren().remove(oldIV);
                }
                if (newIV != null) {
                    getChildren().add(newIV);
                }
            }
        });
        this.imageViewProperty.set(imageView);
    }
}
```

*Alternate approaches and extra information based upon comments*

> If you have to do all that, then it's a weakness in he JavaFX platform. Ideally I would expect there to have been a scale property on the image that one could set so that it uses the SceneGraph to determine it's size.

The solution presented above is just one answer, there are others possible.  The scene graph can be used by binding various properties to the width and height of the parent node or by overriding [layoutChildren](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#layoutChildren--) in the parent node.

Related properties:

- There is a [scale property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#scaleXProperty--) which can be applied to any node.
- A node also has a [transform list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms--) to which a [Scale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Scale.html) may be applied.
- ImageView has a [fitWidth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#fitWidthProperty) and fitHeight properties (use of this is demonstrated in other answers).

I prefer the region subclass approach to a scale property or transform based approach because then the image is automatically sized based upon the layout manager.  The ImageViewPane defined above is just a one-off definition class which can be reused as much as you want, the actual application code to use an ImageView or ImageViewPane is pretty much equivalent.

Another possible approach is to use a Region subclass (such as a Pane), which has a defined CSS style class or id and then to define the [image in CSS as a background](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).  The nice thing about a CSS defined image is that you can then use additional CSS based attributes to define things, like sizing, scaling, positioning and repeats for the image.  This [background](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Background.html#Background-javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage...-) can also be [set programmatically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#backgroundProperty) if desired rather than via CSS.

Related question:

- [Resizing images to fit the parent node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630296/resizing-images-to-fit-the-parent-node)

*To maintain proportional height and width of the image*

The following code can be used in the ImageViewPane class provided above:

```
if (imageView.isPreserveRatio()) {
    if (getHeight() > getWidth()) {
        imageView.setFitWidth(getWidth());
        imageView.setFitHeight(0);
    } else {
        imageView.setFitWidth(0);
        imageView.setFitHeight(getHeight());
    }
} else {
    imageView.setFitWidth(getWidth());
    imageView.setFitHeight(getHeight());
}
```

Comment: If you have to do all that, then it's a weakness in he JavaFX platform. Ideally I would expect there to have been a scale property on the image that one could set so  that it uses the SceneGraph to determine it's size.

Comment: @AndrewS there are [scaleX and scaleY properties on ImageView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setScaleX-double-).  Additionally, you can set [transforms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getTransforms--) on the ImageView, including [scale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Scale.html) transforms.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but someone like me may stumble upon this so here is my solution. I am assuming that **root** is the root node of your scene. However, this should work if your parent node of the **ImageView** is any child of **Pane**.

```
imv = new ImageView();  
root.getChildren().add(imv);
Image image = new Image(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("image.png"))
imv.setImage(image);

imv.fitWidthProperty().bind(center.widthProperty());
imv.fitHeightProperty().bind(center.heightProperty());
```

Comment: what exactly is the `center` in the two bottom lines?

Comment: The center is the parent of the image or the container which is changing size. This works very well.

Comment: Perfect solution. I used center as a vbox and also added: imv.setPreserveRatio(true);
                    imv.setSmooth(true);

Answer (score 3):

Just use a normal pane with a background image, here the css needed.

```
#titleImage{
    -fx-background-image: url("../img/logo.png");
    -fx-background-repeat: stretch; 
    -fx-background-position: center center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to [resize an actual image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951284/javafx-image-resizing), or just to center it?

You can try this: `VBox.setVgrow(root, Priority.ALWAYS);` and see if that's what you want.

Also, be careful with you image, because it's a `png` image. I'm a bit skeptic regarding what's resized there (the actual image or the transparent background).

Comment: I don't want that. To give a clue, open the windows 7 minesweeper and to resize the window by dragging it. You will notice that the images in the grid (the squares) will resize accordingly