# JavaFX - ScrollPane/VBox - Auto shrink

Tags: javafx, autosize, vbox

I'm developing a JavaFX application for kids to control a little robot, the kid would define the commands throught Drag-n-Drops command blocks.
The target area is a Scrollpane with a VBox.

I would like to know if there is any way to make the ScrollPane and VBox autoresizable, thus when I add a node to the Green block it must grow (aldeady doing) and when I remove a node from Green block it must shrink.

Here is the code:

```
// Set to BorderPane#Center<br/>
boxCode = new VBox(0.0);
boxCode.setMinSize(400, 80);
// here I also set MaxSize using Double.MAX_VALUE and USE_COMPUTED_SIZE

paneCode = new ScrollPane(boxCode);
paneCode.setMinSize(400, 80);
paneCode.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;");
paneCode.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
layout.setCenter(paneCode);
```

VBox with the nodes:
[image]

VBox without the nodes:
[image]

Here is my project: [GitHub - Programming Block](https://github.com/wesleyegberto/javafx_projects/tree/master/programming-block)

Thank you!

Comment: You just have to set the minWidth of the VBox appropriatly. vbox.setMinWidth(someValue)

Comment: Sorry for forgot. I just edited to show the code and some more pictures.
I used the ScenicView to inspect and the VBox actually is shrink to minsize but the ScrollPane isn't. It is keeping the last maximum size.

Comment: Why do you need a `ScrollPane` if you don't plan to show the `ScrollBar`s?

Comment: I was showing, but then i decided to let it grow.
I found the cause of this behavior. The left green bar is growing with the scrollpane/vbox, when I remove the line (`leftBackground.fitHeightProperty().bind(paneCode.heightProperty());`), the scrollpane/vbox started to shrink =)
But the left green bar needs to grow together to keep the design.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if I understand the problem. When I set minHeight for `VBox` and `ScrollPane` like in the example below it works for me.

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Button btnAdd = new Button("add");
        Button btnRemove = new Button("remove");
        VBox box = new VBox(btnAdd, btnRemove);
        box.setStyle("-fx-border-color:red");

        btnAdd.setOnAction(e -> box.getChildren().add(new Label("test")));

        btnRemove.setOnAction(e -> {
            int idx = box.getChildren().size();
            box.getChildren().remove(idx - 1);
        });

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(box);
        scrollPane.setMinHeight(200);
        box.setMinHeight(200) ;

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scrollPane);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

Comment: After read you code, I cleaned the code to looks like your and then I found the problem. Thank you!

Now I will try other way to make the left bar grow without break this behavior.

Comment: Just for anyone try something like this, i used the following solution.

[How to resize an image when resizing the window in JavaFx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993550/how-to-resize-an-image-when-resizing-the-window-in-javafx)