# How to make ImageView images in a GridPane resizable?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, gridpane

I have a `GridPane` and in all of the cells `ImageView` containing Images. I successfully managed to make the `GridPane` resizable when I change the window size.

The problem is that when the `GridPane` gets bigger the images won't grow. 
I know you can make them fit when it's in full-screen by:

```
imageView.setFitHeight(100);
imageView.setFitWidth(100);
```

With this code, the images will be too big when not in full-screen.

I want to have them in Window Mode fit `perfectly(Fit(80))` in the cell, as well as in `Fullscreen(Fit(100))`.

My (not so good-looking) idea was to have a method something like:

```
if(stage.inFullscreen) { setFitHeight/Width(100)};
if(stage.inWindowscreen) { setFitHeight/Width(80)};
```

Is there any other more elegant way?

Part of my Code:

```
<GridPane fx:id="Board" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="836.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
...
```

Comment: I think if you posted a [mcve] it would help people to answer your question. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: What happens if you use `StackPane` as the root nodes in the `GridCells` and bind the `ImageViews'` width and heights to the `StackPanes'` width and height?   `img_view1.fitWidthProperty().bind(scrollpane_imageview1.widthProperty()); 
 img_view1.fitHeightProperty().bind(scrollpane_imageview1.heightProperty());`  Where `ScollPane` is replaced by `StackPane`.

Comment: Related: [How to resize an image when resizing the window in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993550/how-to-resize-an-image-when-resizing-the-window-in-javafx)