# How to make a MediaView stays at the center of a Pane in my JavaFX MediaPlayer Application?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I am creating a media player using JavaFX (IntelliJ). I put the MediaView inside a Pane(mediaPane) in the center of the BorderPane. I wanted the mediaView to always stick at the center of the Pane, while keeping its dimension binded with the Pane.

Here is my FXML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="557.0" prefWidth="846.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/20.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.jmediaplayer.MediaPlayer">
   <children>
      <BorderPane fx:id="background" layoutX="193.0" layoutY="111.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <bottom>
            <VBox fx:id="progressParent" prefHeight="129.0" prefWidth="846.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36454F;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Slider fx:id="progressSlider" />
                  <HBox fx:id="controlBar" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <ComboBox fx:id="speedBox" onAction="#changeSpeed" prefHeight="56.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="speed" />
                        <Button fx:id="mediaPreviousButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mediaPrevious" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Previous" />
                        <Button fx:id="mediaResetButton" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mediaReset" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Reset" />
                        <Button fx:id="mediaActionButton" layoutX="134.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mediaAction" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Play" />
                        <Button fx:id="mediaNextbutton" layoutX="196.0" layoutY="10.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#mediaNext" prefHeight="53.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Next" />
                        <Slider fx:id="volumeBar" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="176.0" value="50.0" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </bottom>
         <top>
            <VBox fx:id="titleParent" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="846.0" style="-fx-background-color: #36454F;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Label fx:id="appTitle" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="853.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #fff;" text="JMediaPlayer">
                     <font>
                        <Font name="System Bold Italic" size="42.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Label>
                  <HBox fx:id="mediaSelect" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="46.0" prefWidth="846.0" spacing="10.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label fx:id="mediaTitle" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="705.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #fff;" text="Title">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="20.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Label>
                        <Button fx:id="openFileButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectFile" text="Open" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </top>
         <center>
            <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <StackPane alignment="CENTER" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                     <children>
                        <Pane fx:id="mediaPane" prefHeight="328.0" style="-fx-border-color: red; -fx-border-width: 2;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                           <children>
                              <MediaView fx:id="mediaView" fitHeight="320.0" fitWidth="400.0" onMouseClicked="#mediaViewClicked" />
                           </children>
                        </Pane>
                     </children>
                  </StackPane>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Here is my Controller class

```
package com.example.jmediaplayer;

import static  com.example.jmediaplayer.constants.Constants.*;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MediaPlayer implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private BorderPane background;
    @FXML
    private Pane mediaPane;
    @FXML
    private Label mediaTitle, appTitle;
    @FXML
    private Button mediaActionButton, mediaNextbutton, mediaPreviousButton, mediaResetButton, openFileButton;
    @FXML
    private Slider progressSlider;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> speedBox;
    @FXML
    private Slider volumeBar;
    @FXML
    private VBox progressParent, titleParent;
    @FXML
    private HBox controlBar, mediaSelect;
    @FXML
    private MediaView mediaView;

    private Media media;
    private javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean isPlaying = false, isSeeking = false;
    private File file;
    private final String[] speeds = {"0.25x", "0.5x", "1x", "1.25x", "1.5x", "1.75x", "2x"};

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        setLayout();

//        mediaActionButton.setGraphic(new FontIcon());
        configureProgressSlider();

        for (String speed : speeds) {
            speedBox.getItems().add(speed);
        }
        speedBox.setOnAction(this::changeSpeed);

        mediaView.setFocusTraversable(true);
        volumeBar.valueProperty().addListener((observableValue, number, t1) -> mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeBar.getValue() * 0.01));
    }

    private void configureProgressSlider() {
        progressSlider.setMin(0);
        progressSlider.setMax(1);
        progressSlider.setValueChanging(true);
        progressSlider.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> isSeeking = true);
        progressSlider.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> isSeeking = false);

        progressSlider.valueProperty().addListener((observableValue, number, newValue) -> {
            if (isSeeking) {
                double newTime = newValue.doubleValue() * media.getDuration().toMillis();
                mediaPlayer.seek(Duration.millis(newTime));
            }
        });
    }

    void setLayout() {
        progressSlider.prefWidthProperty().bind(progressParent.widthProperty());

        controlBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(progressParent.widthProperty());

        appTitle.prefWidthProperty().bind(titleParent.widthProperty());
        mediaSelect.prefWidthProperty().bind(titleParent.widthProperty());

        mediaPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(background.widthProperty());
        mediaPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(background.heightProperty());

//        mediaView.setLayoutX((background.getWidth() - mediaView.getFitWidth()) / 2);
//        mediaView.setLayoutY((mediaPane.getHeight() - mediaView.getFitHeight()) / 2);
//        imagePane.prefWidthProperty().bind(background.widthProperty());
        mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(mediaPane.widthProperty());
        mediaView.fitHeightProperty().bind(mediaPane.heightProperty());
    }

    @FXML
    void changeSpeed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (speedBox.getValue() == null) {
            mediaPlayer.setRate(1);
        } else {
            mediaPlayer.setRate(Double.parseDouble(speedBox.getValue().substring(0, speedBox.getValue().length() - 1)));
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void mediaAction(ActionEvent event) {
        if (isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaActionButton.setText("Play");
        } else {
            changeSpeed(null);
            mediaPlayer.setVolume(volumeBar.getValue() * 0.01);
            mediaPlayer.play();
            mediaActionButton.setText("Pause");
        }
        isPlaying = !isPlaying;
    }

    @FXML
    void mediaNext(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void mediaPrevious(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void mediaReset(ActionEvent event) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void selectFile(ActionEvent event) {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        ExtensionFilter extensionFilter1 = new ExtensionFilter("MP4 files (*.mp4)", "*.mp4");
        ExtensionFilter extensionFilter2 = new ExtensionFilter("MP3 files (*.mp3)", "*.mp3");
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter1);
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter2);
        fileChooser.setSelectedExtensionFilter(extensionFilter1);
        file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        setupMedia(file);
    }

    void setupMedia(File file) {
        if (file != null) {
            mediaReset(null);
            String extension = getFileExtension(file);
            mediaTitle.setText(file.getName());
            media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
            mediaPlayer = new javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer(media);
            mediaPlayer.currentTimeProperty().addListener((observableValue, duration, newTime) -> {
                double value = newTime.toMillis() / media.getDuration().toMillis();
                progressSlider.setValue(value);
            });

            if ("mp3".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
                mediaView.setVisible(false);
//                imageView.setVisible(true);
                Image bg_for_mp3 = new Image(Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource(IMAGE_PATH)).toExternalForm());
//                imageView.setImage(bg_for_mp3);
            } else if ("mp4".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
//                imageView.setVisible(false);
                mediaView.setVisible(true);
                mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);
            }
            if (isPlaying) {
                mediaAction(null);
            }
            progressSlider.setValue(0);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void mediaViewClicked(MouseEvent event) {
//        System.out.println("Set Layout X : " + (background.getWidth() - mediaView.getFitWidth()) / 2);
//        System.out.println("Set Layout Y : " + (mediaPane.getHeight() - mediaView.getFitHeight()) / 2);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            System.out.println(background.getWidth() == mediaView.getFitWidth());
            System.out.println(mediaPane.getWidth() == mediaView.getFitWidth());
        });
    }

    String getFileExtension(File file) {
        int index = file.getName().lastIndexOf('.');
        if (index > 0) {
            return file.getName().substring(index+1);
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

I tried to use the binding property to bind the mediaPane with the background(BorderPane) and the mediaView with the mediaPane such as

```
mediaPane.prefWidthProperty().bind(background.widthProperty());
mediaPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(background.heightProperty());
mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(mediaPane.widthProperty());
mediaView.fitHeightProperty().bind(mediaPane.heightProperty());
```

It did the work for making the mediaView responsive but it still only sticks to the Top Left position of the mediaPane as its layoutX and layoutY are set to 0.
Thus, I tried to manually set layoutX and layoutY as

```
mediaView.setLayoutX((background.getWidth() - mediaView.getFitWidth()) / 2);
mediaView.setLayoutY((mediaPane.getHeight() - mediaView.getFitHeight()) / 2);
```

But it did not do anything. I also tried to print the values for `background.getWidth()`, `mediaView.getFitWidth()` and `mediaPane.getWidth()` together and it seems that their values are always equal and so the value of `(background.getWidth() - mediaView.getFitWidth()) / 2` becomes `0` always.

I then tried to remove the Pane and add the mediaView directly in the center of the BorderPane, but then it becomes difficult to bind the heightProperty since I have the Menu in the top and Controls in the bottom.

And I couldn't find any other solution for the problem.

Comment: Trying to layout a node from outside the layout is not the best approach. And in particular, binding layout-altering properties of a child to the layout's width/height properties can cause issues in the layout's own resizing. When doing something like this, it is often better to just create a custom layout and override `layoutChildren()` (and other methods as needed). See [this example](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/3615677) of a "resizable" media view.

Comment: Learn to use [layout panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) (Eden coding also has a [layout tutorial](https://edencoding.com/javafx-layouts/).) You should not have any hard-coded layout positions or sizes, and any time you have a container with a single child is a code smell (e.g. the root `AnchorPane` is redundant and should be removed, as should most of the elements in the center of the border pane).

Answer (score 1):

Creating an auto-resizing `MediaView` is similar to creating a auto-resizing `ImageView`.

- [How to resize an image when resizing the window in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997981/1155209).

Try running the following app and resizing the window to see the effect.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MediaApp extends Application {

    public static final String MEDIA_URL = "https://download.samplelib.com/mp4/sample-5s.mp4";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(
                new Media(MEDIA_URL)
        );
        mediaPlayer.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
        MediaView mediaView = new MediaView(mediaPlayer);

        MediaViewPane mediaViewPane = new MediaViewPane(mediaView);
        mediaViewPane.setPrefSize(600, 400);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(mediaViewPane));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    class MediaViewPane extends Region {

        private ObjectProperty<MediaView> mediaViewProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

        public ObjectProperty<MediaView> MediaViewProperty() {
            return mediaViewProperty;
        }

        public MediaView getMediaView() {
            return mediaViewProperty.get();
        }

        public void setMediaView(MediaView MediaView) {
            this.mediaViewProperty.set(MediaView);
        }

        public MediaViewPane() {
            this(new MediaView());
        }

        @Override
        protected void layoutChildren() {
            MediaView mediaView = mediaViewProperty.get();
            if (mediaView != null) {
                mediaView.setFitWidth(getWidth());
                mediaView.setFitHeight(getHeight());
                layoutInArea(mediaView, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, HPos.CENTER, VPos.CENTER);
            }
            super.layoutChildren();
        }

        public MediaViewPane(MediaView mediaView) {
            mediaViewProperty.addListener((observable, oldMediaView, newMediaView) -> {
                if (oldMediaView != null) {
                    getChildren().remove(oldMediaView);
                }
                if (newMediaView != null) {
                    getChildren().add(newMediaView);
                }
            });
            this.mediaViewProperty.set(mediaView);
        }
    }
}
```

The `MediaView` will [letterbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterboxing_(filming)) automatically if [`setPreserveRatio`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/MediaView.html#setPreserveRatio(boolean)) is `true` (default).  It will also stay centered and resize to fill the available space as that changes due to layout modifications such as resizing the stage, while showing the video at the correct aspect ratio (original aspect ratio of the video).