# How do I have an imageView span the full width of the window when window is full screen

Tags: user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

I am making a main menu screen using Scenebuilder in JavaFX. In the first screenshot, you can see I am trying to put an imageView between the top label and the bottom, as well as having it span the entire width of the screen. However when I preview this scene in fullscreen(as shown in the second image) the imageview's size doesn't change to fit in between the labels and span the entire width of the screen. Basically regardless of the size of the window, the image should not only span the entire width of the window, but the images height should span to fir exactly between the Amazing Airlines label and the Special offers label.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THqhL.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8JV6.png)

I tried changing the size of the image itself on my computer but to no avail. In addition, I also tried changing the anchorpane constraints of the imageview and still no changes. What I expected to happed is the image's height spans to fit in between the two labels above it, while the width spans the entire length of the window when it is full screen.

Comment: Consider using [CSS with the `-fx-background-size` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to resize an image when resizing the window in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22993550/how-to-resize-an-image-when-resizing-the-window-in-javafx).

Comment: If you need a specific answer for your case, provide a [mcve].

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.