# JavaFX resize ImageView in center of BorderPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ImageView in the center of a BorderPane. Left and right are two buttons. The BorderPnae is inside a splitpane. I bind the size of the ImageView to the BorderPane like so:

```
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(borderPane.heightProperty());
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.widthProperty());
imageView.setManaged(false);
```

It rezise but the image is not in the center when setManaged is false. If I remove this lines, the image is nice in the center.
Here is a mwe:

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {

            SplitPane root = new SplitPane();
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
            VBox placeHolder = new VBox();
            
            imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(borderPane.heightProperty());
            imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.widthProperty());
            imageView.setManaged(false);
            
            borderPane.setCenter(imageView);
            imageView.setImage(new Image("pathToImage"));
            root.getItems().addAll(borderPane,placeHolder);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,700,700);          
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpz7l.jpg)

Im looking for a way to archive both. I tried with an Hbox as a container for the buttons and the imageview but that also disables the sizing.

Comment: Why do you need `setManaged(false)`?

Comment: See the `ImageViewPane` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997981/1155209).

Comment: @James_D if I dont, the SplitPane keeps enlarging the field with the ImageView forever, once I change the stage size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to create a "resizable image view" then see the `ImageViewPane` class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22997981/1155209) by [jewelsea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea).

However, your current code seems more like trying to set a *background* image. You have:

> ```java
> imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(borderPane.heightProperty());
> imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(borderPane.widthProperty())
> ```

This will cause the image to be the size of the entire `BorderPane`, not just its "center". In other words, the image is functioning like a background image. Your screenshot would seem to agree with this (the image in your app looks very background-esque). If you want a background image, then you should set the `background` of the `BorderPane` instead of using an `ImageView`.

In code:

```java
BackgroundImage bgImage =
    new BackgroundImage(
        new Image("..."),
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
        BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
        new BackgroundSize(1, 1, true, true, false, false));
borderPane.setBackground(new Background(bgImage));
```

In CSS:

```css
#theBorderPaneId {
    -fx-background-image: url(...);
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-size: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact im not trying to set a background image. I was suspecting a behavior like the one u described, however as u see in the screenshot, the image didnt have the size of the borderpane, only the height. Since the Borderpane has no top or bottom, it should still have fitted with a correct alignment. I checked jewelseas answer with the ImageViewPane and it works. As I understand he adds a new, size adjusted Imageview when the Pane resizes, instead of resizing the existing one.

Comment: Note jewelsea's answer does not replace the `ImageView` but rather sets its `fitWidth` and `fitHeight` properties to be the width and height of the region. That would seem to fit your needs. You may also want to check out [this snippet](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2509295) I made demonstrating "fitted" image views and media views.